# Django Rest Framework : get_queryset returns 'detail': 'Not found'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm, django-class-based-views

Hi I have API which needs to perform Join table with subquery and return queryset. When I print queryset , it prints a queryset with one object in it, but returns 404 'detail' : 'Not Found' error.

I get the customer id in URL, I have to query Customer table to get the corresponding address_id
and send the address details of the address_id from Address table.

Below are the models

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True, auto_created = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    address_id = models.ForeignKey('Address', db_column = 'address_id', on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Address(models.Model):
   address_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
   district = models.CharField(max_length = 20 )
   postal_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10 , blank=True)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

Below is the view

```
class AddressDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    lookup_url_kwarg = "customer_id"
    serializer_class = AddressSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        
        cust_id = self.kwargs['customer_id']
        
        customer_addr_id = Customer.objects.filter(customer_id = cust_id)
        return Address.objects.filter(address_id__in=customer_addr_id.values('address_id'))
```

Below is the url

`path('<int:customer_id>/address',views.AddressDetail.as_view())`

I could print and see object in query set but getting response 'Not found' at client side.
Please let me know if I am missing out something.

Answer (score 0):

`QuerySet.values()` returns a dict-like object with all keys set to string 'address_id' and values  to 'address_id' value, to check the address existence, you can use `values_list` instead.

```
# also you can chain `.distinct()` in the end
Address.objects.filter(address_id__in=customer_addr_id.values_list('address_id', flat=True))
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Yes with .values() on queryset I can see a dict present in it. When I return a queryset , at client side response is "detail": "Not found."